# How do I filter this in Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

Here is my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,default='',unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,default='',unique=True)


class TutorInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='categories')
    about = models.TextField(default='')


class Course(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
```

Now I want to filter the `TutorInfo` such that `sub_category` matches the `sub_category` in their added `Course`. A `Tutor` can have more than one `Course`. Is it possible to write such a query? If not then please advice me what alterations should I do in the models.py

Comment: Please explain your data model a little bit more. There is only one `sub_category` element, which is associated with `Course`.

Comment: consider this situation
/search/tutor/?sub_cat=1
I want TutorInfo such that the id "1" matches the SubCategory id in the user's added courses...

Comment: try `TutorInfo.objects.filter(user__course__sub_category__id__exact=1)`

Comment: It's generally better to supply the code in your question rather than an external url. Stack Overflow has good code highlighting and formatting, and this makes the code readily available, even if the original link is no longer available. I've updated the post for you now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1 is the id of the sub_category you're interested in, use

```
TutorInfo.objects.filter(user__course__sub_category__id__exact=1)
```

whether if `sc` is the sub_category model instance:

```
TutorInfo.objects.filter(user__course__sub_category=sc)
```